# Question related to central limit theorem

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of $i.i.d$ random variables from Gamma$(1,1)$.

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then show that for all $a>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}{P[S_n<a]=0}$.

Please help me with this problem as I am having no clue of where to start.

Comment: Just apply the CLT. Show that $S_n$ tends to a normal (compute its mean and variance), and see that the event $S_n < a$ corresponds to a tail, which probabitily can be bounded by Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: What @leonbloy said, starting at "see that the event..." (no idea why the CLT is mentioned in the title).

Comment: @Did Yes, the CLT is not really needed (with mean and variance is enough) it only can help to visualize the thing.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathrm e^{-a}\mathbf 1_{S_n\lt a}\leqslant\mathrm e^{-S_n}$ hence $\mathrm e^{-a}P[S_n\lt a]\leqslant E[\mathrm e^{-S_n}]=E[\mathrm e^{-X_1}]^n$. The distribution of $X_1$ is $\gamma(1,1)$, that is, standard exponential, hence $E[\mathrm e^{-X_1}]=\frac12$, and $P[S_n\lt a]\leqslant\mathrm e^{a}/2^n\to0$.

**With variances only:** If $S_n\lt a$ and $n\gt a$, then $|S_n-nE[X_1]|\gt n-a$, hence $P[S_n\lt a]\leqslant\mathrm{var}(S_n)/(n-a)^2$ for every $n\gt a$. Now, $S_n$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables with variance $1$ hence $\mathrm{var}(S_n)=n$. Finally, $P[S_n\lt a]\leqslant n/(n-a)^2\to0$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks.